# How do I create a checkbox that's disbaled by default in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-5, isenabled

I'm using Rails 5.  How do I create a checkbox that is disabled (not clickable) by default?  I tried

```
<%= f.check_box :mybox, :tabIndex => '1', :enabled => false %>
```

but the resulting checkbox is still rendered as enabled.

Comment: There is no `enabled` attribute, just `disabled`: 

`<%= f.check_box :mybox, tabIndex: '1', disabled: true %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` attribute:

```
<%= f.check_box :mybox, tabIndex: '1', disabled: true %>
```